# error: too many arguments to function call, expected 1, have 4 when using make compile hsdis in macOS Monterey

Tags: c, macos, gcc, jvm-hotspot

I want to build the hsdis in macOS Monterey 12.3 with Intel CPU, this is the command I am using:

```
hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk-updates/jdk11u/
cd jdk11u/src/utils/hsdis
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/binutils-2.26.1.tar.bz2
tar xjf binutils-2.26.1.tar.bz2
rm binutils-2.26.1.tar.bz2
```

when I using this command to compile:

```
make BINUTILS=binutils-2.26.1 ARCH=amd64
```

the terminal shows error:

```
Making all in po
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
gcc -o build/macosx-amd64/hsdis-amd64.dylib -I/Users/dolphin/source/third-party/jdk11u/src/utils/hsdis/binutils-2.26.1/include -I/Users/dolphin/source/third-party/jdk11u/src/utils/hsdis/binutils-2.26.1/bfd -Ibuild/macosx-amd64/bfd -DLIBARCH_amd64 -DLIBARCH=\"amd64\" -DLIB_EXT=\".dylib\"  -fPIC -O hsdis.c -shared -lz build/macosx-amd64/bfd/libbfd.a build/macosx-amd64/opcodes/libopcodes.a build/macosx-amd64/libiberty/libiberty.a
hsdis.c:320:32: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 1, have 4
                               bfd_big_endian(native_bfd),
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/macosx-amd64/bfd/bfd.h:512:30: note: expanded from macro 'bfd_big_endian'
#define bfd_big_endian(abfd) ((abfd)->xvec->byteorder == BFD_ENDIAN_BIG)
                             ^
/Users/dolphin/source/third-party/jdk11u/src/utils/hsdis/binutils-2.26.1/include/dis-asm.h:341:27: note: 'disassembler' declared here
extern disassembler_ftype disassembler (bfd *);
                          ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [build/macosx-amd64/hsdis-amd64.dylib] Error 1
(base)
```

does anyone facing this error? what should I do to fix it? PS: My computer is 2019 MacBook Pro with x86 Intel CPU, not the ARM M1 CPU. I have tried to build it on ARM but failed. This is my hardware information:

```
Hardware Overview:

  Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro15,1
  Processor Name:   6-Core Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  2.6 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    6
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 12 MB
  Hyper-Threading Technology:   Enabled
  Memory:   16 GB
  System Firmware Version:  1731.100.130.0.0 (iBridge: 19.16.14243.0.0,0)
  OS Loader Version:    540.100.7~23
  Activation Lock Status:   Enabled
```

Comment: I can not change the tag, I do not know which tag would be proper with this question. @GhostCat

Comment: I gave you some ideas ... the java tag attracts JAVA developers. But you are facing an issue while compiling that hotspot tool.

Comment: Thank you for your patients and help.@GhostCat

Comment: And guessing: maybe your issue is that you want to build something for Intel, but your Mac has the M1 chip (or vice versa?) So please A) enhance your question with that information and B) check if that is something you can configure in the build or so. Maybe you just can't build that tool for your architecture?

Comment: The Mac is Intel CPU, not M1 chip.@GhostCat